# dataLayer.push from one element disrupts dataLayer.push of another

Tags: html, wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm building [WP website using DIVI theme](http://www.wro.place/smart-bedroom). The label which is supposed to be pushed into the dataLayer gets stuck somewhere with the default "not set" value.

In order to push the values I used the script:

```
<script>
    function init() {
        dataLayer.push({'sectionLabel': 'Test section'});
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

Triggered by:

```
<p class="GASectionVisible">
```

It works in [isolation](http://www.wro.place/test/) but not on the [main website](http://www.wro.place/smart-bedroom/).

Now the interesting part:

I implemented very similar tag on toggles on the same page - they're fired only after the toggle is opened to reveal the content with triggering class. They work perfectly well but I think they somehow disrupt dataLayer.push from the new elements - headers. When I pasted the **exact same code from headers into the brand new, empty page they fire and push information correctly and passes the values as expected**. When I paste their exact copy on my site, the tag still fires but shows label "not set".

The only **workaround** I figured out was to put the triggering element and script on a separate page and then embed it on the main site via iFrame. It works, but I can't do it on all the elements I need to track.

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, Please consider using a [**MCVE** (**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)..

Comment: Thanks, I updated the description. Hope it' better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem why it's not firing on `http://www.wro.place/smart-bedroom/` page because you overriding `onload` function in custom.min.js. That means that your code below will never fire because it's overridden.

```
<script>
  function init() {
    dataLayer.push({'sectionLabel': 'Test section'});
  }
  window.onload = init;
</script>`
```

Correct way to do that is

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    dataLayer.push({'sectionLabel': 'Test section'});
}, false);
```

**UPDATE**
Based on discussion in comments, the new solution is:

```
var firedSections = []
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { 
    var sections = document.querySelectorAll('.et_pb_section');
    for(i=0;i<sections.length;i++)
    {
        if (firedSections.indexOf(i) == -1 && checkVisible(sections[i])) {
          firedSections.push(i)
          dataLayer.push({'sectionLabel': 'Number '+i});
        }
    }
});


function checkVisible(elm) {
    var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
    return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}
```

You need to add this code **only once on the page** and it will push into datalayer once you scrolling the page.

Comment: Victor, thank you for getting involved! I used your code on my simple [test page](http://www.wro.place/test). The label gets pushed, but when tag of the visible Section 1 fires, it pushes the label from the script of the Section 2 which is below the fold.

I think that all the scripts are fired at the same time and all the tags are grabbing the value from the last script that fired (the lowest one on the page). Do you have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: Yes, all tag fired at the same time. But how do you want to fire it? Should it fire a tag only when the section is appearing on screen during scroll?

Comment: Exactly. I want to track the depth of visit.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Now it's firing datalayer once you scrolling and section is visible on the screen

Comment: Thanks for the edit Victor. I just checked it. The updated script doesn't push the label value - the previous one did. Now Tag Manager displays "not set" when firing 1st section and "Section 1" with the 2nd section. I tried placing code both as a part of the 1st section, as well as placing it in the separate section on top of the test page. I'm working on alternative solution in paralel to ours. I'll post the status if I succeed.

Comment: Can you just install my script and i will tell you what's wrong

Comment: I installed the script in the header of the website as you asked and it broke the layout. Please take take into consideration, that I'd like to push custom label value for each element and not Section 1,2,3. Also, some elements will not be sections e.g.: in section 2, im rather interested if the last (wi-fi) Blurb had time to get on screen, rather then if just the section (perhabs empty, because of the set delay in animations) was in the viewport. Hope it makes sence.

Comment: It's broke layout because you made mistake with html tags. Please check html of your page and you will find an issue. You right, my code is just sending "Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3" into datalayer once you scrolling. And it's working with sections only.  If you know JS, then you will be able to use my code as the starting point of your solution and customize it as you need.

Comment: You are right - I left some residue in the header and it caused the layout issue. My bad. Even though the solution is not exactly what I was aiming for, I truly appreciate that you donated your time and talent into my project. Thank's a lot Vic! :)